# rCharts HighCharts X-axs grouping

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, highcharts, rcharts

Basically I would like to use scatter plot to show a person use how many hours to perform a task. So, the Y-axis is Time (hour) and X-axis is Day (irregular dataset). My question is, can I do X-axis category Day grouping so the data (Time) can be populated correctly?

```
Day   Time    Task
---------------------------- 
Mon    1.3      A
Mon    0.6      B
Tue    2.1      A
Wed    1.5      C
Fri    0.4      C
Sun    0.2      B
```

For now, i am able to plot the chart using code below. Assume 'dat' is the data frame for the sample above.

```
a <- hPlot(Time~ Day, data =dat,  group= 'Task' ,type = "scatter", title = "Data chart" )
```

The output for the code above able to group the X-axis for Day, but the Time data will not follow and not populating correctly. It will show Mon=1.3, Tue=0.6, Wed=2.1 etc...

Then i explore another approach by using direct passing the parameters to highchart with the code below through series.

```
   a$series(name = 'task plot', type = 'scatter', color= 'blue' ,data =??? )
```

This can plot the scatter plot as well using rcharts highchart, but i do not know how to handle the data=??? in R code so the highchart will get the data as below into highchart to ensure the X-axis grouping with Time data populated correctly. The x values is corresponding to categories array defined in axis as per how highchart work.

```
    xAxis: {
            categories: ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu']
        },
...
series: [{
                type: 'scatter',
                data: [
                    [0,1.3], // Mon 1.3
                    [0,0.6], // Mon 0.6
                    [1,2.1], // Tue 2.1
                    [2,1.5]  // Wed 1.5
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This forum seems not really many active users. : )
I managed to solve my own problem after did some further study on the behavior of the rcharts and highcharts for both method above. Here is the approach for the benefits of everyone who interested to do the same thing.

If you study the behavior of highchart X-axis grouping, it will do grouping if you assign each X with a value instead of string. Therefore, for both method i have to first create a index grouping based on the Day which will serve as my X value for the plot. I use 'match' function to create a new column 'Index' as below corresponding to Day.

```
Day   Time    Task   Index
---------------------------- 
Mon    1.3      A      0
Mon    0.6      B      0
Tue    2.1      A      1
Wed    1.5      C      2
Fri    0.4      C      3
Sun    0.2      B      4
```

Method#1, in the hPlot approach, i have to use Index as my X value so the plot will do the X-axis grouping and the Y value (Time) will populate correctly.

```
a <- hPlot(Time~ Index, data =dat,  group= 'Task' ,type = "scatter", title = "Data chart" )
```

After the plot, you will observe the X-axis label by the Index value. Then, you can just re-label them with the code below. I have to use unique since the Day is a irregular dataset and have repeated day as you can see.

```
a$xAxis(categories=unique(dat$Day))
```

Method#2, by using the R to highcharts i have my own new learning (probably I am new). Instead of using a$series, i change it to use a$data which can take x and y value for data input to the plot.

```
 a$data(name = 'task plot', type = 'scatter', x=dat$Index, y=dat$Time )
```

And of course same as method#1, need to re-label the a$xAxis by using the unique Day.

Now, i have both methods can work for the plot that i wanted and it work perfectly fine.